# Python check if a variable appears in another variable

Tags: python, authentication

I'm a beginner to Python. I'm using the request module to get the text from a website that contains blacklisted users for the login system of my program. I want to know how to check if a variable appears in another variable such as, "if variable appears in variable2: do something"

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: you have already described that: `if var1 in var2: do something`

Comment: You need to be *specific* about what you mean. "variables" don't exist in other variables. An object can define what containement means, and you can check that using the `in` keyword. You need to be specific about what objects you are working with.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, we don't put "SOLVED" to mark a question has been answered. That's already being done by the green checkmark next to the answer. Also, we don't copy the solution/answer into the Question. They are already in the Answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share your code. It would give a better understanding of what you need to do. I think the below code will work.

```
import requests

x = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com')

if variable in x.text:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check that using the `in` keyword -

```
if object1 in object2:
   #do something
```